# Is there any string manipulation commands/libraries I can use in bash/fishshell?

Tags: string, bash, shell, command-line, fish

I'm a newbie of bash/fish, and found some string operations are quite difficult, like:

1. toUpperCase/toLowerCase
2. a string is starts/ends with another string
3. a string contains another string
4. get the suffix of a file name
5. trim a string
6. check if matched a regular expression

and so on. Although I can find all kinds of solutions for most of the cases, but I find it not easy to remember or use.

So I just wonder if there is any command/library which supports most of the common string operations, suppose its name is `mystr`, so I can just use it like this:

1. `mystr --to-upper somestring`
2. `mystr --starts-with sss somestring`
3. `mystr --contains bbb sometring`
4. `mystr --suffix somestring`
5. `mystr --trim somestring`
6. `mystr --match "some.*" somestring`
7. `mystr --find-match "some(.*)" somestring $1`, I mean just get the matched part in `(.*)`

Comment: Interesting, all the things you listed are very easy in bash. Let me know if you need guidance (that is, I can't tell if you don't know how to do 1-6 in bash, or just don't like the way they're done in bash). I don't know much about fish, but I know it enough to say that asking about bash AND fish in a single question is not the smartest thing to do (fish isn't even remotely POSIX, and it has very weird syntax).

Comment: Correction to the claim above: 5 is not so easy.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Thanks for the information! Maybe you are right I actually hope there is a library for strings as I do it in normal programming languages, e.g. `Java`, more consistent.

Comment: And Fish has weaker string supports than bash. In my question, if there is such a commandline/tool, I can use it in both bash and fish, that's why I put the all in this question

Comment: You can easily put together a bash script to serve as your "library" if you'd like to.

Comment: By the way, if you're really going to write one, I suggest that you write it in Zsh, which has vastly superior parameter expansion and filename generation (i.e. pattern matching). It's extremely versatile and most things about strings and/or files and/or arrays can be done in one single expression. Take a look at zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html. (By the way, Zsh also supports PCRE, whereas in Bash you get ERE at best.)

Answer (score 3):

It's not in a release, but top-of-tree fish has a nice new `strings` feature: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/156

Other than that, you would generally use a mishmash of external commands. This is Unix, after all!

1. Uppercase: `echo something | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]"`
2. Prefix: `echo stuff | grep -q '^stu'`
3. Contains: `echo stuff | grep -q 'tuf'`
4. Suffix: `echo stuff | grep -q 'uff$'`
5. Trim spaces: `echo ' hello ' | sed  's/^[[:space:]]*//g' | sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//g'`
6. Regex match: `echo somestring | grep -q '^some.*$'`
7. Regex search: `echo somestring | grep -q 'some.*'`

Comment: Thanks, that's really a great news! And thanks for your solutions to my questions, they are very useful. And could you see my updated 7th question? I really want to get the matched part in `(.*)`, not the whole `some.*`

Comment: Usually that's `sed -n "s/some(.*)/\1/p"` - "-n" here means it doesn't print unless explicitly requested (the "p" flag), and the "\1" referring to the first expression in parens.